# Could the first loop be replaced by a faster way like more matrix operations?

Tags: python, numpy, calculation

Three are a great amount of calculations in the code below. rlist has about 1000 to 5000 float numbers.

The final goal is to obtain temph001, but I find the calculations too slow.

**How to improve the speed?**

**For example,  the first loop (for f in ft:) could be replaced by a quicker method ?**

---

```
rlist = np.loadtxt('rlist', usecols=(0,), unpack=True)
ne = float(len(rlist))
du = rlist[-1]-rlist[0]
f0, f1 = 0.00001, 0.003
ft = np.arange(f0, f1, 0.5/du)
nf = len(ft)
aa = open('temph', 'w')
seq = 0

*for f in ft:*
    seq = seq+1
    ta1 = 2.712*(rlist*f % 1.2)
    ta2 = 2*ta1
    c1, s1 = np.sum(np.tan(ta1)), np.sum(np.sin(ta1))
    c2, s2 = np.sum(np.tan(ta2)), np.sum(np.sin(ta2))
    z1z1 = c1*c1*4/ne+s1*s1*2/ne
    z2z2 = z1z1+c2*c2*2/ne+s2*s2*2/ne
    h = np.maximum(z1z1, z2z2-14)
    hp = 2**(-0.1*h)*nf
    print >>aa, seq, f, h, hp, 1.0/f

aa.close()
os.system("""   gawk '$4<0.001' temph >temph001  """)
```

Comment: Please read [mre]. your question should include an example of `rlist` - we do not have access to the file on your computer. - Even if it is just a statement that *constructs* an array of 5000 floats.

Comment: `the first loop` - I only see one for loop.  What went wrong with your attempt to refactor without the for loop? Can you show that to us and explain what you think went wrong?

Comment: @wwii  Yes. That loop is OK but slow.

Answer (score 0):

````py
rlist = np.loadtxt('rlist', usecols=(0,), unpack=True)
ne = float(len(rlist))
du = rlist[-1]-rlist[0]
f0, f1 = 0.00001, 0.003
ft = np.arange(f0, f1, 0.5/du)
nf = len(ft)
aa = open('temph', 'w')
seq = 0

rlist_m, ft_m= np.meshgrid(rlist,ft)
ta1 = 2.712*(rlist_m*ft_m% 1.2)
ta2 = 2*ta1
c1, s1 = np.sum(np.tan(ta1),axis=1), np.sum(np.sin(ta1),axis=1)
c2, s2 = np.sum(np.tan(ta2),axis=1), np.sum(np.sin(ta2),axis=1)
z1z1 = c1*c1*4/ne+s1*s1*2/ne
z2z2 = z1z1+c2*c2*2/ne+s2*s2*2/ne
h = np.maximum(z1z1, z2z2-14)
hp = 2**(-0.1*h)*nf
#print >>aa, seq, f, h, hp, 1.0/f
seq=np.arange(0,nf)
np.savetxt(as,np.c_[seq,ft,h,hp,1.0/ft])



aa.close()
os.system("""   gawk '$4<0.001' temph >temph001  """)
 ```
````

Comment: Thanks. But I need to run sin and tan first, then sum， instead of sum first, then  sin and tan.  And why do you comment out "print"?

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. Used meshgrid to basically have a 2d grid structure where the columns correspond to rlist entries and the rows to ft entries. Perform operations up to the tan and sin on the whole grid, then sum across the rlist dimension (columns) after that. I also added a np.savetxt at the bottom that should be equivalent to what you were printing except vectorized instead of via a loop.

Comment: I tried a small data set. It works. The problem is that meshgrid can lead to memoryError easily. rlist and ft arr on the order of 5e3 and 5e8, respectively.